# Is assert(false) ignored in release mode?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, posix, assert

I am using VC++. Is `assert(false)` ignored in release mode?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If compiling in release mode includes defining NDEBUG, then yes.

See [assert (CRT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9sb57dw4.aspx)

Comment: The documentations states "The assert routine is available in both the release and debug versions of the C run-time libraries." Looking at the assert.h header though, it's certainly true that defining NDEBUG before including it will cause assert() to compile to a no-op. However, it is entirely possible for release mode code that does not define NDEBUG to cause an assertion to abort. I just wanted to clarify my own understanding and share what I found.

Answer (score 8):

IIRC, assert(x) is a macro that evaluates to nothing when NDEBUG is defined, which is the standard for Release builds in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

The assert macro (at least it is typically a macro) is usually defined to no-op in release code. It will only trigger in debug code. Having said that. I have worked at places which defined their own assert macro, and it triggered in both debug and release mode.

I was taught to use asserts for condition which can "never" be false, such as the pre-conditions for a function.

Answer (score 2):

Only if NDEBUG is defined I think (which it will be by default for Visual C++ apps).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a mistake to rely too much on the exact behavior of the assert.  The correct semantics of "assert(expr)" are:

- The expression expr may or may not be evaluated.
- If expr is true, execution continues normally.
- If expr is false, what happens is undefined.

More at http://nedbatchelder.com/text/assert.html

Comment: The correct semantics is described in ISO C. If assertions are enabled (`NDEBUG` is not defined prior to including `<assert.h>`) then if the controlling expression of an `assert` compares equal to zero, then the text of the expression, the file and line number are printed in some implementation-defined message on the standard error stream. Then the `abort` function is called. (As of C99, the message is required to include the function name also.)

Comment: When creating performance code, building without asserts can be important to get right in a release build.

Answer (score 1):

same for GNU :

```
  #ifdef    NDEBUG

  # define assert(expr)     (__ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0))
```