# EMSGSIZE when trying to send data on raw IP packet

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, raw-sockets

My code sends a raw IP packet to `12.12.12.12` and fails because of `EMSGSIZE`. I think that it limits my packet according to Ethernet MTU, but it should send packets <= 65,535 bytes (IPv4 MTU).

I've tried to send a packet to `127.0.0.1` and this worked well, but the error occurs when I send a packet to a non-local IP.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd;
    assert((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) != -1);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(1818);
    assert(inet_aton("12.12.12.12", &addr.sin_addr) != -1);
    assert(connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != -1);

    char buffer[2000];
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    assert(send(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == sizeof(buffer));

    assert(close(fd) != -1);
}
```

I expect that the code will work without any errors because I send a packet that is less than IP MTU. Troubleshoot the code with `strace`:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1818), sin_addr=inet_addr("12.12.12.12")}, 16) = 0
sendto(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 2000, 0, NULL, 0) = -1 EMSGSIZE (Message too long)
a.out: compile.c:22: main: Assertion `send(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == sizeof(buffer)' failed.
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=8814, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
Aborted
```

Comment: Everything in the `assert` is removed in release builds. The entire `assert` and expression is effectively turned into whitespace. You should do something like `ssize_t result = send(fd, ...); assert(result == sizeof(buffer));`. In release builds the `send` will survive. Also see [Is assert(false) ignored in release mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270488/608639)

Comment: If you perform `ssize_t result = send(fd, ...);` then you can check `result`. According to the [`send(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send): *"On success, these calls return the number of characters sent. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately."* You should be able to check `errno` for something like `EMSGSIZE`, which is documented in the man page: *"If the message is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol, the error EMSGSIZE is returned, and the message is not transmitted."*

Comment: I compile the code using `gcc test.c`, and `NDEBUG` is not defined, so the assertions work well (as we can see in the `strace` message).

Comment: when compiling on linux with gcc, no compile errors.  When performing the link step, no errors.  However, when trying to run the posted code the very first call to `assert()` causes the code to abort.  STRONGLY suggest removing/replacing the calls to `assert()` with something like:  `if( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0)
    { 
  perror( "socket failed" );
 }`

Comment: making use of the suggested call to `perror()` results in: `socket failed: Operation not permitted`.   This is suggestive that the combination of the parameters to `socket()` are not valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think that it limits my packet according to Ethernet MTU, but it should send packets <= 65,535 bytes (IPv4 MTU).

Since PMTU is on by default it will only send packets fitting in the MTU. Your packet doesn't. 
From [raw(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html):

> **By default, raw sockets do path MTU** (Maximum Transmission Unit)
>          discovery.  This means the kernel will keep track of the MTU to a
>          specific target IP address and **return EMSGSIZE when a raw packet
>          write exceeds it**.  When this happens, the application should decrease
>          the packet size.
>   **Path MTU discovery can be also turned off** using the
>          IP_MTU_DISCOVER socket option or the
>          /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_no_pmtu_disc file, see ip(7) for details.  When
>          turned off, raw sockets will fragment outgoing packets that exceed
>          the interface MTU.  However, disabling it is not recommended for
>          performance and reliability reasons.